# method put in fastapi not working/ 405 method not allowed

Tags: python, jinja2, fastapi

I am having problem with Fastapi, Jinja2 put method.
My task is to save form, here is ajax in html file

```
    function submitForm() {
        var url = 'http://localhost:8000';
        let id = document.getElementById("person-id").value;
        var data = {id: id};
        fetch(url, {
          method: 'PUT',
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
          headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(response => console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response)))
        .catch(error => console.log('Error:', error));
```

Here py method update

```
@router.put("/{id}",  response_class=Response)
async def update(request: Request, id: str, req: UpdateModel = Body(...)):
   updated = await update(id, req.dict())
   return templates.TemplateResponse('index.html', context={'request': request})
```

Update is not working, console is just showing

**405 method not allowed**
T

Comment: Your `url` variable is just pointing to `http://localhost:8000`. It needs to point to `http://localhost:8000/{id}`

Comment: @im_baby Only 405 method not allowed, apart from that no error. I meant uvicorn works on other part

Comment: @im_baby yes because this is put, when I check Referer: I got this value http://localhost:8000/id

Comment: Try it in Postman and see what the results are. When you PUT to `http://localhost:8000` you get 405, when you PUT to `http://localhost:8000/{id}` you get 200

Answer (score -1):

## 1. create a simple backend

### 1.1 create a `test.py`

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn
import datetime

from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
app = FastAPI()

origins = ["*"]
 
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World", "datetime": datetime.datetime.now(), "test": 'this is a test'}


class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: Optional[str] = None
    price: float
    tax: Optional[float] = None


@app.put("/items/{item_id}")
async def create_item(item_id: int, item: Item):
    return {"item_id": item_id, **item.dict()}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app='test:app', reload=True, debug=True)
```

### 1.2 run `test.py` file

```sh
python test.py
```

## 2. front part

### 2.1 create a `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <script>
        const person = {
            name: 'apple',
            description: 'this is a test',
            price:200,
            tax: 400123598
        }

        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/40', {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify(person)
        }).then(function(respones) {
            return respones.json();
        }).then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

### 2.2 use chrome brower to open `index.html` and check Console of chrome

[image]